# What determines which crew missions are available?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Obviously your level in the relevant crew skill plays a factor, but I see different missions all the times, and sometimes no higher level missions at all (that I had previously had available.
I can't see a rhyme or reason to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a random assortment based on your skill level. Every mission has a minimum skill before it becomes availiable, and there is a maximum number of availiable missions at each tier, which is based on your skill and increases with it.

You can refresh the list by zoning into a new area, or logging out and back in.

Comment: nowai. *That's* good to know.

Comment: are you sure it still works?  In beta it did, I would just zone back and forth from my ship to get the mission I wanted, but yesterday I tried to do the same thing, and after many attempts, I was getting the same missions, so I was wondering if they patched that recently

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you could be seeing a bug that's hiding your missions, from the [Crew Skills FAQ](http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=530#anchor12) on the official forums:

> **12. Help! I can't see any of my Crew Skill missions or companions! What do
>   I do?!**
>
> This is a bug with the UI (user interface). If you are experiencing
>   this problem, all you have to do is hit [CTRL+U] twice to reset your
>   UI. Hitting it once will turn it off, hitting it again will turn it
>   back on.

Secondly, they come from a random assignment of missions that changes as you run missions (if you can't see any you want at the moment just run a couple of Companion Gift missions to force them to refresh).

And lastly, at higher levels you also want to be checking the GTN for single-use crew missions. You're given less missions at the higher levels and expected to buy some of them from other players. Traded missions often give well above average results, but also have a chance of failing absolutely, so they are a risk but often pay off.

Comment: they are not single-use that I know of. They just take a while to reappear (you can see them as having an unlocked padlock before the name)

Comment: Purchased missions **are** single use. They won't reappear unless you buy them again.

Comment: @Rodolfo Personal experience (and the forums) suggest they are single-use. See this forum thread, you may have been seeing a bug that made your bottom mission look like an unlocked one: http://www.swtor.com/community/showthread.php?t=208337